# R session crash when using ggplot2 to color geom_point by factor in OSX 10.9.5 (R 3.1.2)

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, crash

I just downloaded the new version of R 3.1.2 and am now struggling with crashes occurring when using `ggplot2`. I downloaded R-3.1.2-mavericks.pkg and am operating OS X 10.9.5. I am also working in R Studio (Version 0.98.501).

I am working with a data frame MCbyrep2 that looks something like this:

```
MCbyrep2 <- data.frame("Stn" = c(rep(10,3), rep(18,3), rep(2,3)),
                       "Substrate" = (rep(c("lam","pul","xyl"), 3)),
                       "TN" = c(rep(3.605, 3), rep(6.39, 3), rep(8.87, 3)),
                       "kcRate" = c(8.36, 1.64, 3.11, 10.85, 0, 0, 3.93, 1.56, 0))
```

where Stn and Substrate are factors, and TN and kcRate are continuous numeric variables.

I am trying to plot TN vs. kcRate in `ggplot2`. This works just fine when I color the points "dark green" using this code:

```
TN <- ggplot(data = MCbyrep2, aes(x = TN, y = kcRate)) + geom_point(color = "dark green") 
TN
```

but when I try to color the points by Stn using the code below, this results in a crash in R.

```
TN <- ggplot(data = MCbyrep2, aes(x = TN, y = kcRate)) + geom_point(aes(color = Stn))
TN
```

What might be causing this crash? I tried removing and re-installing `ggplot2` (as well as `reshape2` and `plyr`) packages but to no avail.

Comment: what if you use factor(Stn)?

Comment: No luck, same crash. And class(MCbyrep2$Stn) => "factor".

Comment: you say the data looks something like this, so you mean that you are using a different data frame than in the example? are you using a fresh r session or --vanilla? with only ggplot loaded?

Comment: I posted a minimal example of my original data but I get the same problem using the posted data frame as well. I've tried running this code a few times with new R sessions, first load library(ggplot2), same problem.

Comment: Just tried running this code in the R console and in Terminal (rather than R Studio) thinking maybe I could just update R Studio, but still got a crash.

Comment: Complete uninstall and reinstall or R and R Studio worked. Uninstall of R with the Terminal command rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript. I installed the R version R-3.1.2-snowleopard.pkg instead of mavericks this time, so I'm not sure if it was the changed version or the uninstall that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Complete uninstall and reinstall or R and R Studio worked.

Uninstalled R with the Terminal command rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript.

I installed the R version R-3.1.2-snowleopard.pkg instead of R-3.1.2-mavericks.pkg this time, so I'm not sure if it was the changed version or the uninstall that fixed the problem.